# This program doesn't give me any output? Generating prime numbers from 2 to n-1

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

> Write a function named list_of_primes that accepts a positive integer
>   n and returns a sorted list (ascending order) of all the prime numbers
>   between 2 and n (including 2 but not including n)

```
def list_of_primes (n):

    list = []

    for i in range (2, n):
        isPrime = True
        for j in range (2, i):
            if (i % j == 0):
                isPrime = False

        if isPrime:
            list.append(list)
    return (list)



#Main Program
n = int(input("Enter a integer value: "))
result = list_of_primes (n)
print (result)
```

I cannot get any output for this code. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you running python2.7, or python3? It cannot be both.

Comment: Change this `list.append(list)`  to this: `list.append(i)`. You are appending an empty to list to your list. You aren't getting any of the values you want. You want to collect the numbers you are detecting as prime or not. In this case it is `i` per your iteration. Also, as just mentioned below, don't use `list`. Use `list_` or `l`, or something different but meaningful.

Comment: `list` has already a meaning in Python, don't overwrite it. Instead, use other meaningful names, like `myList`.

Comment: I wouldn't call `myList` any more meaningful than `list`; it's just not in use already. `list_of_primes` would be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `list.append(i)` rather than `list.append(list)`.

Comment: Um, so should I append 2 in the list before handed?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think it does spit out 2.

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your variables after the in-built list in python, i also created another function `is_prime` to check if a number is a prime number while iterating

```
def list_of_primes(n):

    res = []
    for i in range(2, n):
        if is_prime(i):
            res.append(i)

    return res


def is_prime(n): # checks if a number is prime
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


#Main Program
n = int(input("Enter a integer value: "))
result = list_of_primes(n)
print(result)
```

Comment: also brackets are redundant in python

Comment: In `list_of_primes()`, you don't need to check all the way up to `n`.  You can check up to `int(n ** 0.5)`

Comment: i don't think that's right remember we're checking from 2 to n-1

Comment: If `n % i` is equal to 0, that means that some number times `i` equals `n`.  If that number were *smaller* than `i`, then we would have found it already.  That means that it must be greater than or equal to `i`.  If `i * >=i` is equal to `n`, `i` cannot be more than the square root of `n`.

Comment: you're right but you're still getting it wrong about where it should be applied it should be in the `is_prime` function, list of primes has to loop through all numbers in the range and check if they are prime numbers and it should be `range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1)` because python's range is non-inclusive. for example checking if 25 is prime the square root is 5 but `range(5)` will stop at 4

Comment: I'm sorry; that's what I meant.